# Wind turbine that is efficiant from all angles

Tags: design, wind-power

What shape propeller with a large surface are, would be best propelled from the wind from behind and from the side as well as the front while facing the sun?
I am thinking a pinwheel, but maybe there is a better design?
[image]

Comment: A vertical axis with something like a barrel with blades.

Comment: Check out Savonius rotor designs. In fact some are shown in the answer...

Comment: This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a “vertical axis wind turbine”.

See below for some design examples:

[image]